# Apache rewrite rule and keep the url unchanged?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^ar$       /index2.html
```

but i need to keep the url in the address bar unchanged after the redirect.
ie. if the user typed http://mydomain.com/ar i need to redirect him to /index2.html but keep the url as is.
any idea of how to do so??
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Lairsdragon said is correct.  However, if you have more than one rewrite rule in your config, you will want to add the `[L]` flag to the end in order to prevent other rules from being applied.

Answer (score 1):

The Pattern in the RewriteRule is wrong. A

```
RewriteRule ^/ar$       /index2.html
```

should to exactly what you want: It rewrites the /ar to index2.html without telling the web browser about the redirection.

Comment: ok... what shall it be... i tried too many flags like L,NC,R=301, R and too many others, but didn't get it as i want... so what shall it be??

Comment: No flags at all :-) Just tried on my webserver works like a charm.

Comment: this is what i know!! it is supposed to keep the url unchanged if you didn't provide any rewrite flag!! but this didn't work with me!! any idea??

Comment: Could it be that you dont really redirect to a static file? If another apache module is involved like mod_proxy, mod_jk etc this ma lead to an external rewrite via HTTP code 302

Comment: @Alaa If you remove that rule completely do you still get the redirect? If so you probably have another rule or directive that is being applied first.