# Apache: Open same .php file with any URN (abc.com/<blabla>) but keep the URL

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, mod-rewrite, apache2, website

I basically found a part of my solution here: [Apache rewrite rule and keep the url unchanged?](https://serverfault.com/questions/253608/apache-rewrite-rule-and-keep-the-url-unchanged)

but I want to do more.

I want to open a "template.php" site which comes up on any URN entered. So if I open abc.com/blabla, template opens and URL stays abc.com/blabla. If I enter abc.com/lalala, template opens and URL stays abc.com/lalala.

I think this is what I want:

```
RewriteRule ^/$       /template.php
```

Besides that, I want my mainsite abc.com to open index.php and also use a rewrite for https which I do like this:

```
    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule     ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

How can I achieve both in one config? Doesnt the https part mess up the URN part?

Comment: "I think this is what I want" - And what does that do? What do you think `^/$` means? "any URN" - do you literally mean _any_ URL, even URLs that would otherwise map directly to a filesystem resource? Just to confirm... these directives are in your main server config / virtual host container?

Comment: abc.com/<anything> should point to template.php, the only exception is abc.com/index.php which is the mainsite and should point to index.php (+ https).

Yes, template.php and index.php are located in my rootdir /var/www/<vhost>/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/$       /template.php
> ```

Assuming this directive is in a *server* or *virtualhost* context (ie. not a *directory* or `.htaccess` context), then this will only match requests for the document root (ie. `/`) and ignore `/blabla` and `/lalala`.

To match `<anything>`, except `index.php` (or an empty URL-path, assuming `index.php` is set as the DirectoryIndex) then do something like the following instead:

```
 RewriteRule ^/(index\.php|template\.php)?$ - [L]
 RewriteRule ^ /template.php [L]
```

The first rule stops any further processing if `/` or `/index.php` or `/template.php` is requested, which allows your main site (ie. `index.php`) to be accessed and prevents a rewrite loop.

The second rule rewrites all other URLs (whether they map directly to filesystem resources or not) to `/template.php`.

It's unusual that you wouldn't want static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.) to be excluded from this rewrite, but you've confirmed this in comments.

> ```
> RewriteEngine   On
> RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} !=on
> RewriteRule     ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
> ```

Since you are in the main server config (ie. not `.htaccess`) then you shouldn't be using mod_rewrite to issue the HTTP to HTTPS redirect anyway. You should have a simple mod_alias `Redirect` in the non-canonical `<VirtualHost *:80>` container.

> Doesnt the https part mess up the URN part?

No. (To answer this specific question - if you were using mod_rewrite.)

This is of course assuming you have the directives in the correct order. The external redirect from HTTP to HTTPS should appear first.